# Is there a way to position divs on top of each other without using position absolute?

Tags: jquery, css

So I have this structure(ignore russian text):

```css
.sliders-container {
    position: relative;
 width:100%;
 float:left;
}



.slider{
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 float: left;
}

#prev, #next{
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 100;
}


#prev{
 float:left !important;
}

#next{
 float:right !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliders-container">
    <a id="prev">Prev</a>
 <a id="next">Next</a>
 <div class="slider">
     <p class="container-text">
      <h1>Join US</h1>
  </p>
  <p class="container-text">
      <strong>Можно ли присоединиться?</strong> Да, конечно. Но сначала <a href="#">прочитайте наши базовые ожидания</a> — что мы ждем от каждого вступающего в UTG.
  </p>
 </div>
 <div class="slider">
     <p class="container-text">
   <h1>Преданность, участие и общение</h1>
  </p>
  <p class="container-text">Чем больше вы вкладываете в группу, тем больше получаете взамен. Если вы хотите играть с нами, вы должны быть готовы участвовать в жизни группы. Мёртвый груз никому не нужен. Сила группы зависит от активного участия членов сообщества. Если вы не отписываетесь в темах, когда вас просят, не участвуете в общении на форумах, в чате или не принимаете участия в играх, то вы являетесь никем для этой группы.
  </p>
 </div>
 <div class="slider">
  <p class="container-text">
   <h1>Зрелость</h1>
  </p>
  <p class="container-text">Вы должны быть готовы серьёзно отнестись к игре. Всем дуростям своё время и место, и вы должны уметь определять это время. Помимо этого, вы должны быть способны на адекватное, нормальное общение как в игре, так и вне её.
  </p>
 </div>
 <div class="slider">
  <p class="container-text">
   <h1>Желание учиться, совершенствоваться и быть частью команды</h1>
  </p>
  <p class="container-text">ArmA — это не та игра, где вы играете сами. Успех зависит от каждого. Чтобы быть эффективным в игре, вы должны знать свою роль, структуру командования, тактику и базовые процедуры, уметь общаться, работать с напарниками и использовать своё оружие. Если вы не командный игрок и не в состоянии выдержать того, что кто-то будет отдавать вам приказы, то можете дальше не читать. На данный момент накопилось много различной информации помимо БТП — начиная с этого текста, заканчивая обширной базой знаний по используемым модам. Вы должны быть готовы самостоятельно изучить всю необходимую информацию и разобраться в ней. Нам не нужны те, кто не способен уделить этому время.
  </p>
 </div>
 <div class="slider">
  <p class="container-text">
   <h1>Требования</h1>
  </p>
  <p>Следующие вещи являются <i>обязательными</i> без исключения:</p>
  <ul>
   <li>
                <a href="http://www.arma3.com/" target="_blank">Лицензионная версия ArmA3</a>. Естественно это также подразумевает установленный <a href="http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam">Steam</a>, так как игра распростряняется только через него.
            </li>
   <li>
                <a href="http://teamspeak.com/?page=downloads" target="_blank">Клиент TeamSpeak 3</a>. Он будет нужен для общения во время игр.
            </li>
   <li>
                <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone" target="_blank">Микрофон</a>. Если у вас его нет, можете зайти в любой компьютерный магазин и купить любую самую дешёвую гарнитуру.
            </li>
   <li>
                <a href="http://www.skype.com" target="_blank">Skype клиент</a>. Он понадобится для быстрого и комфортного общения внутри группы.
            </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="slider">
  <p class="container-text">
   <h1>Что дальше?</h1>
  </p>
  <p class="container-text">
   <li>
                Прочитайте <a href="http://ttp2.tacticalgaming.kiev.ua/" target="_blank">базовые тактики и процедуры</a>.
            </li>
   <li>
                Свяжитесь через Skype с <strong>messiahukraine</strong>. 
            </li>
  </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

And I have all the divs being positioned one after another. What I want is this:
I want all the divs to be on top of each other(i will use it build a jQuery slider later), but I want to do it without using `position:absolute`

```css
.sliders-container {
    position: relative;
 width:100%;
 float:left;
}



.slider{
 position: absolute;
 overflow: hidden;
 float: left;
}

#prev, #next{
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 100;
}


#prev{
 float:left !important;
}

#next{
 float:right !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliders-container">
   <a id="prev">Prev</a>
   <a id="next">Next</a>
   <div class="slider">
    <p class="container-text">
     <h1>Join US</h1>
    </p>
    <p class="container-text">
       <strong>Можно ли присоединиться?</strong> Да, конечно. Но сначала <a href="#">прочитайте наши базовые ожидания</a> — что мы ждем от каждого вступающего в UTG.
    </p>
   </div>
   <div class="slider">
    <p class="container-text">
     <h1>Преданность, участие и общение</h1>
    </p>
    <p class="container-text">
       Чем больше вы вкладываете в группу, тем больше получаете взамен. Если вы хотите играть с нами, вы должны быть готовы участвовать в жизни группы. Мёртвый груз никому не нужен. Сила группы зависит от активного участия членов сообщества. Если вы не отписываетесь в темах, когда вас просят, не участвуете в общении на форумах, в чате или не принимаете участия в играх, то вы являетесь никем для этой группы.
    </p>
   </div>
   
   <div class="slider">
    <p class="container-text">
     <h1>Зрелость</h1>
    </p>
    <p class="container-text">
     Вы должны быть готовы серьёзно отнестись к игре. Всем дуростям своё время и место, и вы должны уметь определять это время. Помимо этого, вы должны быть способны на адекватное, нормальное общение как в игре, так и вне её.
    </p>
   </div>
   
   <div class="slider">
    <p class="container-text">
     <h1>Желание учиться, совершенствоваться и быть частью команды</h1>
    </p>
    <p class="container-text">ArmA — это не та игра, где вы играете сами. Успех зависит от каждого. Чтобы быть эффективным в игре, вы должны знать свою роль, структуру командования, тактику и базовые процедуры, уметь общаться, работать с напарниками и использовать своё оружие. Если вы не командный игрок и не в состоянии выдержать того, что кто-то будет отдавать вам приказы, то можете дальше не читать.
     На данный момент накопилось много различной информации помимо БТП — начиная с этого текста, заканчивая обширной базой знаний по используемым модам. Вы должны быть готовы самостоятельно изучить всю необходимую информацию и разобраться в ней. Нам не нужны те, кто не способен уделить этому время.
    </p>
   </div>
   
   <div class="slider">
    <p class="container-text">
     <h1>Требования</h1>
    </p>
    <p>Следующие вещи являются <i>обязательными</i> без исключения:</p>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.arma3.com/" target="_blank">Лицензионная версия ArmA3</a>. Естественно это также подразумевает установленный <a href="http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam">Steam</a>, так как игра распростряняется только через него.</li>
    <li><a href="http://teamspeak.com/?page=downloads" target="_blank">Клиент TeamSpeak 3</a>. Он будет нужен для общения во время игр.</li>
    <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone" target="_blank">Микрофон</a>. Если у вас его нет, можете зайти в любой компьютерный магазин и купить любую самую дешёвую гарнитуру.</li>
    <li><a href="http://www.skype.com" target="_blank">Skype клиент</a>. Он понадобится для быстрого и комфортного общения внутри группы.</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   
   <div class="slider">
    <p class="container-text">
     <h1>Что дальше?</h1>
    </p>
    <p class="container-text">
     <li>Прочитайте <a href="http://ttp2.tacticalgaming.kiev.ua/" target="_blank">базовые тактики и процедуры</a>.</li>
     <li>Свяжитесь через Skype с <strong>messiahukraine</strong>.</li>
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Is is possible to do without using `position:absoulte`? Maybe some jQuery workaround?

Comment: Which div you are referring to? You have two sliders-containers? or are you referring to slider which I don't think that's the case.

Comment: I have one ```sliders-container``` and inside of it are many ```slider```s, so I want sliders to be positioned on top of each other, like in 2nd example, but without using ```position:absolute```;

Comment: Why is it that you can't use `position: absolute;`?

Comment: @twiz that will ruin the responsive layout of the website, because text will get out of the div borders, because it will force me to set a fixed ```height``` size, and divs with ```position:absolute``` don't accept height in %

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using negative margins.

```
.slider{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: -100%;
}
```

Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8j1ex5rb/1/)

The benefit of using this approach over `position: absolute` is that it doesn't remove the affected content blocks from the document’s normal flow.